# Inheritance with GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a few domain classes that are setup as such:

```
Person
  - Name

OrganizationPerson extends Person
  - Role
  - Organization

User 
  - Person
```

In Bootstrap.groovy, I'm creating a sample user:

```
def person = OrganizationPeople.findOrSaveWhere(name:'admin', emailAddress: 'steven@admin.com')
person.save(flush:true)

def user = User.findOrSaveWhere(person: person, organization: organization,
                                username: 'admin', password: 'asdfasdf')
```

However, when the code ends up hitting the `User.findOrSaveWhere` I get an error:

```
Error initializing the application: object references an unsaved
transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
com.eventrosity.Person; nested exception
```

However, before the `OrganizationPerson` inherited `Person`, this wasn't an issue. The `person.save(flush:true)` saved the item.

Is this an issue in GORM? Is this an issue that I need to be aware of in the context of domain objects and inheritance?

Comment: is your `organisation` there saved?

Comment: At that point of time its not. However the error is pointing towards the Person.

Comment: true, but would you mind trying?

Comment: Just did, it came back with the same error about the nested exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably just a standard validation problem - the `OrganizationPeople` instance save failed, so you can't proceed with saving the `User`. When you call `save()` (or something like `findOrSaveWhere` that calls it for you) there won't be an obvious error or an exception. But it's easy to check if the save succeeded:

```
def person = OrganizationPeople.findOrSaveWhere(...)
if (person.hasErrors()) {
    // handle the error
}
else {
    def user = User.findOrSaveWhere(...)
    if (user.hasErrors()) {
        // handle the error
    }
}
```

Note that the explicit `person.save()` call is redundant since `findOrSaveWhere` already called `save()` for you.

Comment: I got errors about the Person variable going into the organization before (object references an unsaved
transient instance, that only got fixed when I explicitly did a .save(flush:true)

Comment: You're right.. doh... now I have to fight over a null hasMany collection.